# Temp folder runs out of inodes

Tags: linux, wordpress, ubuntu, woocommerce, litespeed

I have a LiteSpeed server with a Wordpress/woocommerce website on it.

Every few days my /tmp folder runs out of inodes, which effectively disables the website.

Here is what I get, after running `df -i`, please note the `/dev/loop0` part.

```
    root@openlitespeed:~# df -i
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            501653    385  501268    1% /dev
tmpfs           504909    573  504336    1% /run
/dev/vda1      7741440 888567 6852873   12% /
tmpfs           504909      6  504903    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           504909      3  504906    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           504909     18  504891    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15           0      0       0     - /boot/efi
/dev/loop0       96000  78235   17765   82% /tmp
tmpfs           504909     11  504898    1% /run/user/0
```

The output from `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M  616K  394M   1% /run
/dev/vda1        58G   43G   16G  74% /
tmpfs           2.0G  128K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/loop0      1.5G   13M  1.4G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/0
```

The folder is full of "sess_" files.
Right now I constantly monitor the folder and issue:

```
find /tmp/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +5 -delete
```

Which kinda helps, but is not ideal.

How can I reconfigure to increase the inodes?
Where to look?

Edit:
I have redis, and it's enabled in LiteSpeed Cache plugin.
It's all on DigitalOcean VPS, with 2CPUs and 4 GB RAM. Ubuntu 18.04.
Why does it even have just 96k inodes with the size of 1.5G, when tmpfs has much more?

Comment: increase inode I think may need to re-format it , you can create a larger tmp partition , or move php session files somewhere else , or even use different session handler like memcached or redis

Comment: Edited my original questions and clarified a bit. I do use redis.

Comment: Hey @mgatner, where you able to find answer to this. I am having the same exact problem in Digital Ocean droplet. It keeps on filling up.